# jQuery/JS Select Array Element where element contains n?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Got myself all confused here.

I've got a string bellow, which I'm using .split to form an array.

```
1:new bubble:143:753:3:rgba(65,146,160,0.7)|2:new bubble:370:949:3:rgba(174,76,221,0.7)|3:new bubble:557:940:3:rgba(55,33,11,0.7)|4:new bubble:494:1170:3:rgba(61,68,191,0.7)|5:new bubble:431:736:3:rgba(233,54,149,0.7)|6:new bubble:236:836:3:rgba(14,133,141,0.7)|
```

the string contains what I've called "bubbles" each bubble is split up by | so you can see there are 6 bubbles (and a blank one)

I then use .split again this time using : as the split. so I effectively have an array which can load into variables;

```
Array 
bubble[0]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5]
    }
bubble[1]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5] 
        }
bubble[2]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5] 
        }
bubble[3]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5]     
        }
bubble[4]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5]
        }          
bubble[5]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5]
        }
bubble[6]{
            id = bubbleinfo[0],
            name = bubbleinfo[1],
            posx = bubbleinfo[2],
            posy = bubbleinfo[3],
            priority = bubbleinfo[4],
            color = bubbleinfo[5]
        }
```

so that's basically how they form. i assuming anyway.

my issue is however i need to be able to update name, posx, posy, priority and colour by selecting the second array dimension's "id"

so psudo code would be something like

```
foreach bubble[i]
do
if ID = $_post[ID]
get element 3 - replace new value
get element 2 - replace new value
i++
```

does anybody understand me? if you do then please could you help me with it. as i've no idea how to structure the function to do this.

thanks

Owen

Comment: How are you creating this string? I'd suggest you to encode your data as JSON instead of a custom format. As for your problem, [it seems you just need to iterate over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), although you could improve this using an object and creating an `id->bubble` mapping.

Comment: the data has to be stored inside a cookie, hence it being structured like that.

Comment: You can store json in a cookie... its just text.

Comment: ive never actually used json, could you give me an example how one of my strings would be re-formatted to fit it please?

Comment: Maybe like this: `[{"posx": 143,"posy": 753,"priority": 3, "color": "rgba(65,146,160,0.7)"}, ...]`. You can choose however you want it to. The format is similar to JavaScript object literals. More information: http://json.org/

Comment: It would look similar to what you have typed out there as an example of your data... that is barring a couple issues JSON syntax. Most server side languages have json decoder/encode built in so you can take native structures of the language and convert them to JSON. Likewise some browsers have built in `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` which will convert back and forth. IF not you can always use the json2 javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.each could do this for you if I'm understanding your question correctly:-

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

You can find more info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

---

a clearer example:

```
var idYouAreLookingFor=2;
$.each(bubble, function(index, value) { 
  if(value.id==idYouAreLookingFor)
  {
      value.name='test';
     //profit.
  }
});
```

Comment: ive just re-read over my question and realised how unclear i was. basically i need a function that checks through all the array elements until it finds element[0] that is equal to my inputted query.

Comment: ey, i understand this but how would i update the values in the 2nd and 3rd element and put them back into the string?

Comment: is your issue how to you re-serialize the data into that strange format once you have updated it? if so array.join (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) would solve it for you - but seriously look at using json instead! (http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

Use JSON as storage format. Now, I don't know which value is which, but here is an example for JSON encoded data:

```
[{"posx": 143,"posy": 753,"priority": 3, "color": "rgba(65,146,160,0.7)"}, ...]
```

You can then use [`JSON.parse` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to create a JavaScript object from this data, which will look like this:

```
// var obj = JSON.parse(json); is the same as:

var obj = [
    {
        posx: 143,
        posy: 753,
        priority: 3, 
        color: "rgba(65,146,160,0.7)"
    },
    ...
];
```

It also seems that the IDs of your "bubbles" are continuous, 1-based. If you make them zero-based, you don't have to store them explicitly. The ID would be the index in the array.

Then you can change the values like so:

```
obj[id].posx = newvalue;
obj[id].posy = another_newvalue;
```

and afterwards serialize the the whole array with [`JSON.stringify` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

and store it in the cookie.

`JSON` is available for older browser with [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: okay thanks, i'll look into this as im failing at the moment as you can see http://the-dot.co.uk/dev/Project%20v1 if Felix you have some form of IM client can talk, maybe you could clear up some of the functions using json for me for a reasonable fee?